# Attempting to dynamically pass parameters to a stored procedure from excel 2013 calling DB2 mainframe

Tags: vba, excel, stored-procedures

I have a requirement to dynamically pass parameter to a called SP which pulls data from the mainframe.

My excel connection string is:

```
DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};UID=k9751x1;PWD=********;MODE=SHARE;DBALIAS=RISCTEST;
```

The command text is:

```
call K9751DB.SP_GETRTSDB_BYDBTSNOPTLIKEDTTM('', '', '','2017-10-01 23:25:59.999999','2')
```

[Connection Properties, for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQo6T.png)

I'm attempting to pass the first 3 parameters: `LPARSSID`, `DBNAME`, `TSNAME`

I've created the following VBA code and assigned an activeX button. The code appears to debug fine. but when I click on the button noting appears to happen.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim LPARSSID As String 'Declare LPARSSID as String
Dim DBNAME As String 'Declare DBNAME As String
Dim TSNAME As String 'Declare TSNAME As String

LPARSSID = Sheets("RTSbyDBTSDTE").Range("B2").Value  'Pass value from cell B2 to LPARSSID variable
DBNAME = Sheets("RTSbyDBTSDTE").Range("B3").Value    'Pass value from cell B3 to DBNAME variable
TSNAME = Sheets("RTSbyDBTSDTE").Range("B4").Value    'Pass value from cell B4 to TSNAME variable`

Pass the Parameters values to the Stored Procedure used in the Data Connection
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("RISCTEST - ParmPass").ODBCConnection
.CommandText = "call K9751DB.SP_GETRTSDB_BYDBTSNOPTLIKEDTTM('" & LPARSSID & "', '" & DBNAME & "', '" & TSNAME & "','2017-10-01 23:25:59.999999','2')"
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("RISCTEST - ParmPass").Refresh

End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

End Sub
```

Not sure if `ODBCConnection` is correct.

I appreciate any suggestions you may have.

Tku,
Jeff A

Comment: I just tried using your code to invoke a SQL Server stored procedure (I don't have DB2 available for testing) and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have a big Microsoft Access database that I use with our scary old bookkeeping system for running complex reports. It's Access 2007 with an iSeries v6, DB2 SQL, and AS400. I tried using Excel 2007 in thye beginning, but it couldn't handle it. But I'll take a stab anyways...

I'm not certain of the way you're using the With block and the Refresh method. I usually see With blocks used with a property or object. But looking at your With block, there's nothing in it. That may be why nothing happens. It just says...

```
With <yourcommand>.Refresh
    'nothing here
End With
```

...so it may be doing something, but since the With block is empty, it doesn't do anything with any data that might be returned. And since I don't know what the SP is supposed to do, I can't say. And what I mean is, I'm assuming it is supposed to return some data, because if not and it just does something hidden on the server, you would know because you'd probably have other means to verify the activity.

Instead of using the With block, remove the Refresh command from that block and put the command on a line by itself:

```
    ...
    Pass the Parameters values to the Stored Procedure used in the Data Connection
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("RISCTEST - ParmPass").ODBCConnection _
    .CommandText = "call K9751DB.SP_GETRTSDB_BYDBTSNOPTLIKEDTTM('" & LPARSSID _
    & "', '" & DBNAME & "', '" & TSNAME & "','2017-10-01 23:25:59.999999','2')" _
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("RISCTEST - ParmPass").Refresh
End Sub
```

Comment: The `With` block isn't empty. It refers to the `ODBCConnection` property of the specified Connection, sets the `.CommandText` and then does the `Refresh`. I agree that the `Refresh` probably belongs outside of the `With` block, but my testing suggests that it *should* work either way. (At least it did for me.)

Comment: Ahh..ok. With the line-wrapping it's hard to tell what's where. So `ActiveWorkbook.Connections("RISCTEST - ParmPass").Refresh` is on a line by itself within the With block..?

Comment: *"... is on a line by itself within the With block..?"* - That's how I interpreted it, and that's what worked for me.

Comment: Thanks - sorry about the text skew, it apparently is an undocumented 'feature' :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry; this is long. A second answer to your question, and extension of my first answer. My eyes were tired at the end. Please excuse any strange typos or seemingly missing sentences. If your eyes glaze over halfway through, there's actual working code (I hope) at the end.

Holy cow, this has been a bull to figure out. But I threw on a saddle, and I've been riding it since yesterday morning when I first replied to the OP. I think the issue isn't the strangeness of DB2 (as far as I can figure out yet, lol), but because of the way Excel implements ODBC, SQL, and queries.

I decided to make this a learning exercise. I work in Access w/VBA all day at work, with an occasional foray into Excel, but I never dove in to Excel queries before, and I'm much more familiar with Access VBA for this sort of thing. I've been wading through the No-Help file, VBA Object Explorer, and MSDN online documentation. But it was still monumentally confusing. Then I found this web page, which in the first few paragraphs, gives a perfectly coherent picture of the situation: https://www.cimaware.com/expert-zone/creating-basic-data-reports-with-listobjects-and-querytables

There are multiple layers of Excel UI bling involved, and the VBA object hierarchy for the associated collections & objects can take multiple, sometimes simultaneously abbreviated & parallel forms. It's a bit crazy how Excel throws things all over the place:

1) `Excel` > `Workbook/s` > `Connections` > `WorkbookConnection` > `ODBCConnection`

2) `Excel` > `Workbook/s` > `Worksheet/s` > `ListObject/s` > `QueryTable/s`

3) `Excel` > `Workbook/s` > `Worksheet/s` > `QueryTable/s`

4) `ListObject` > `QueryTable` > `WorkbookConnection`

5) `QueryTable` > `WorkbookConnection`

I'll explain all these items:

- `Excel`, `Workbooks`, `Workbook`, `Worksheets`, and `Worksheet` are obvious.
- Each `Workbook` contains the `Connections` collection for every `Worksheet` in it.
- `Connections` can have connections of any type, whether it be file-based from `TXT` or `XLS`, web-based via `HTTP`, or the one we're looking at closely here: `ODBC`.
- For some reason Microsoft broke the naming convention and called it a `WorkbookConnection`, rather than just `Connection`.
- Then we arrive at the `ODBCConnection`, which has the gorey innards of the ODBC settings.
- What can be confusing, all throughout these items, the ODBC connection string and SQL query string are repeated, and sometimes it's hard to tell what property/object links one item to another.
- A `QueryTable` (QT) can be created in two places: contained within a `ListObject` (LO) or it can live independently right on a worksheet.
- When a QT is contained in a LO (as introduced in Excel 2007), that's what gives us some of the bling I mentioned. Specifically, the `Table Tools` group and `Design` tab on the ribbon. This is where all the fancy settings & formatting come from, such as the alternating rows colors and dropdown boxes on the column headers.
- When a QT is independent from a LO, the resulting query results & controls are simple and utilitarian. In fact they look and work just like they did in Excel 2003.

1) `Excel` > `Workbook/s` > `Connections` > `WorkbookConnection` > `ODBCConnection`

This is where the connection is stored. This is equivalent to the connections you see in the "Workbook Connections" window from the ribbon at Data > Connections.

2) `Excel` > `Workbook/s` > `Worksheet/s` > `ListObject/s` > `QueryTable/s`

This is what you get when you create a query from scratch in the Excel UI, by using any of the items in the "Get External Data" group that result in an ODBC connection to an SQL server. In my case I already have a collection of DSN files for DB2, so all during this experimentation I've only been using DSN files listed on the "Existing Connections" window.

3) `Excel` > `Workbook/s` > `Worksheet/s` > `QueryTable/s`

This is what you get if you use VBA to programmatically create a stand-alone `QueryTable` that's not contained in a `ListObject`. So far I haven't found any way to do this in the UI; I think no matter what's done, any queries created through the UI of Excel 2007 or later force containment within a `ListObject`.

4) `ListObject` > `QueryTable` > `WorkbookConnection`

This chain of objects is what you get from the UI. I found the `WorkbookConnection` need not be explicitly created in the `Connections` collection ahead of time. Any time a `QueryTable` is created, the connection is always created as a sort of side product.

5) `QueryTable` > `WorkbookConnection`

This is the simplest form, perhaps best described as the old way, and gives a query result and controls like those of Excel 2003 and 2000.

Now, after all this research, I think I understand what's happening in your code, and what you might do differently. The core bit is here:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("RISCTEST - ParmPass").ODBCConnection
.CommandText = "call K9751DB.SP_GETRTSDB_BYDBTSNOPTLIKEDTTM('" & LPARSSID & "', '" & DBNAME & "', '" & TSNAME & "','2017-10-01 23:25:59.999999','2')"
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("RISCTEST - ParmPass").Refresh

End With
```

Cleaned up perhaps like this (in my style of extensive subdivision):

```
Dim wb           As Excel.Workbook
Dim conns        As Excel.Connections
Dim conn         As Excel.WorkbookConnection
Dim odbc         As Excel.ODBCConnection
Dim connName     As String
Dim connCmdText  As String
Dim spName       As String
Dim p1           As String
Dim p2           As String
Dim p3           As String
Dim p4           As String
Dim p5           As String

'Set up the parameter strings for everything.

connName = "RISCTEST - ParmPass"
spName = "K9751DB.SP_GETRTSDB_BYDBTSNOPTLIKEDTTM"
p1 = LPARSSID
p2 = DBNAME
p3 = TSNAME
p4 = "2017-10-01 23:25:59.999999"
p5 = "2"

'I use this trick to make quoted-strings within quoted-strings more
'readable. It's more lines of code, but easy to make with copy &
'paste, and when your eyes get blurry and tired and crossed and those
'double and single quotes start to look like triple single quotes
'and you can't tell quadruple single-quotes from double double-quotes,
'it can be a life saver. =-)

'This is the actual command.

connCmdText = "call spname('p1','p2','p3','p4','p5')"

'Now replace all the parameter codes with the real data. Be careful when
'choosing the names of the codes so they don't conflict with any correct
'strings already in the command string, or mayhem will result. Use goofy
'punctuation to make them more unique if necessary.

connCmdText = VBA.Replace(connCmdText, "spname", spName, , , vbTextCompare)
connCmdText = VBA.Replace(connCmdText, "p1", p1, , , vbTextCompare)
connCmdText = VBA.Replace(connCmdText, "p2", p2, , , vbTextCompare)
connCmdText = VBA.Replace(connCmdText, "p3", p3, , , vbTextCompare)
connCmdText = VBA.Replace(connCmdText, "p4", p4, , , vbTextCompare)
connCmdText = VBA.Replace(connCmdText, "p5", p5, , , vbTextCompare)

'Now to the business.

Set wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
Set conns = wb.Connections
Set conn = conns.Item(connName)
Set odbc = conn.ODBCConnection
odbc.CommandText = connCmdText
conn.Refresh

'The with block wasn't even needed. (I think.)
```

Now looking at that, I don't see a QT. Is there more to your code that includes one, which you didn't include in your OP..? If the code you posted is all you have, I don't see anything to tell Excel where to put the query result. But unless there's something outstandingly different, you've shown enough to allow some supposition for different code to get what you want.

Here's an actual working procedure for my DB2 system that I worked out today to figure out this issue. It posts a basic Excel 2003-style query result at A1 on Sheet1. I've only blotted out the user credentials and IP of the server for anonymity. This is the most basic implementation of a query in Excel VBA: the independent-QT.

```
Sub TestQT()

    Dim connStr        As String
    Dim connCmdText    As String
    Dim destRangeAddr  As String
    Dim ws             As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim qts            As Excel.QueryTables
    Dim qt             As Excel.QueryTable
    Dim destRangeRng   As Excel.Range

    'Set up the connection string and other variables for the query.

    destRangeAddr = "A1"
    connCmdText = "SELECT * FROM VIPDTAB.BEERXT"
    connStr = _
        "ODBC;" & _
        "DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};" & _
        "UID=********;" & _
        "PWD=********;" & _
        "SIGNON=1;" & _
        "QRYSTGLMT=-1;" & _
        "PKG=QGPL/DEFAULT(IBM),2,0,1,0,512;" & _
        "LANGUAGEID=ENU;" & _
        "DFTPKGLIB=QGPL;" & _
        "DBQ=VIPDTAB;" & _
        "SYSTEM=***.***.***.***;" & _
        "FILEDSN=NOTHING;"
        'In experiments I found FILEDSN doesn't need to be anything, it can
        'simply be FILEDSN=DUMMY, if you wish to use a DSN-less connections,
        'as I do. Also, obviously the password is visible and as such is a
        'security issue.

    'Define the sheet.

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    'Clean up the sheet. Useful if the query is run repeatedly, and to avoid the
    'runtime error that says "overlapping pivot table".

    ws.Cells.Clear
    ws.Cells.ColumnWidth = 8

    'Now to business.

    Set destRangeRng = ws.Range(destRangeAddr)  'Range object to paste the data.
    Set qts = ws.QueryTables                                'The QT collection.
    Set qt = qts.Add(connStr, destRangeRng, connCmdText)    'Create the query

    'Now run it. 'False makes Excel lock up during long queries, so True is best.

    qt.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True

End Sub
```

Now, to merge all these ideas together to solve your problem. Everything is nearly identical, except the last few lines. I have no way of testing this since of course I'm not on you system, but I did run the debugger on it to catch any blatant typos. So shout me back if you need more help:

```
Sub TestQuery2()

    Dim wb           As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws           As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim qts          As Excel.QueryTables
    Dim qt           As Excel.QueryTable
    Dim conns        As Excel.Connections
    Dim conn         As Excel.WorkbookConnection
    Dim destRangeObj As Excel.Range
    Dim destRangeTxt As String
    Dim connName     As String
    Dim connDesc     As String
    Dim connStr      As String
    Dim spName       As String
    Dim connCmdText  As String
    Dim p1           As String
    Dim p2           As String
    Dim p3           As String
    Dim p4           As String
    Dim p5           As String

    connName = "RISCTEST - ParmPass"
    connDesc = "" 'set the description as/if desired
    connStr = _
        "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};" & _
        "UID=k9751x1;" & _
        "PWD=********;" & _
        "MODE=SHARE;" & _
        "DBALIAS=RISCTEST;"
    destRangeTxt = "$A$1"

    'Set up the procedure call by replacing the parameters.
    'It's much more readable than quotes within quotes.

    connCmdText = "call spname('p1','p2','p3','p4','p5')"
    spName = "K9751DB.SP_GETRTSDB_BYDBTSNOPTLIKEDTTM"
    p1 = Sheets("RTSbyDBTSDTE").Range("B2").Value
    p2 = Sheets("RTSbyDBTSDTE").Range("B3").Value
    p3 = Sheets("RTSbyDBTSDTE").Range("B4").Value
    p4 = "2017-10-01 23:25:59.999999"
    p5 = "2"

    'Replace all the parameters.

    connCmdText = VBA.Replace(connCmdText, "spname", spName, , , vbTextCompare)
    connCmdText = VBA.Replace(connCmdText, "p1", p1, , , vbTextCompare)
    connCmdText = VBA.Replace(connCmdText, "p2", p2, , , vbTextCompare)
    connCmdText = VBA.Replace(connCmdText, "p3", p3, , , vbTextCompare)
    connCmdText = VBA.Replace(connCmdText, "p4", p4, , , vbTextCompare)
    connCmdText = VBA.Replace(connCmdText, "p5", p5, , , vbTextCompare)

    'Define the worksheet and destination.

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set destRangeObj = ws.Range(destRangeTxt)

    'Clean up the sheet. Useful if query is run repeatedly. If used as
    'such, the .Clear has to happen before the .Add method, or a runtime
    'error will ocurr due to the old query blocking the new one. I didn't
    'save the message, it was something about "pivot table overlap".

    ws.Cells.Clear 'wipe all values, formatting, conections, and queries
    ws.Cells.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 8

    'Something I noticed that's different between an LO/QT and independent-QT,
    'with an LO/QT, the connection is attached to the table, literally. So the .Clear
    'may not delete the connection if it was created by an independent-QT. The following
    'bit of code should take care of that, by looping through the connections and
    'deleting any connection that already exists with the same name.


    Set wb = ws.Parent
    Set conns = wb.Connections
    For Each conn In conns
        If conn.Name = connName Then
            conn.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next


    'Now the business.

    Set qts = ws.QueryTables
    Set qt = qts.Add(connStr, destRangeObj, connCmdText)

    'Now both the query and connection have been created. The connection name, which
    'appears in the Workbook Connections window, needs to be set. When the QT is created
    'in the .Add procedure above, the connection is also created, but there's no way to
    'specify its name, so it just uses the name "Connection". But that can be changed
    'after the fact, as can the connection description, if desired.

    Set conn = qt.WorkbookConnection
    conn.Name = connName
    conn.Description = connDesc

    'And finally, the fireworks:

    qt.Refresh True

End Sub
```

Comment: spinjector - 
Thanks again for your reply and the reference. It certainly helps clarify.   
Finally got a chance to 'play' with this over the weekend. when I run it, I get Runtime error: 1004.The line of code flagged is:  Set qt = qts.Add(connStr, destRangeObj, connCmdText)

Tku,
Jeff A (jagosta@metlife.com)

If you want to contact me direct, I can share the WB)

Answer (score 0):

spinjector - 
First off, let me say WOW... this is amazing stuff and I truly appreciate your taking the time to delve and share.

Secondly, (and quite honestly), you're skills in this area are far and above that of mine. While I've been using excel for many years to pull data from z/OS (my bailiwick as a DBA / SysProg) and have written a few (basic) macros, I've never gotten deep into the bowels as you quite apparently have... IMPRESSIVE.

The method I use to set up my connection is via Data, Other Sources, From MS Query, Choose Data Source, input the query / StoredProc, and assign a taget for the data (see below). Honestly pretty Excel 101, but works well and is fairly easy to implement.

However that being said, I like most techies, love to learn and share and will be attempting what you have shared as time allows. In addition, I'm looking to become more VBA savvy and have discussed some formal (or informal) training with my current management.

Again - your efforts and willingness to share are very much appreciated.

Tku,
Jeff A

To set up excel to use odbc

•   Open excel
•   Select data
•   Select get external data
•   Select from other sources
o   From SQL Server (for SQL Server)
   Enter server name (ie for dbstatus: xxxxxxxx\xxxx)
   Connect
o   From Microsoft Query (For DB2 LUW, z/OS, Oracle)
   Select the data source
   Create a new one if needed
•   Name the data source
•   Choose the driver type
   Connect
   Enter server name
o   Select database / table
o   Select view type / display location
o   Optionally select properties
   In Command text box, enter query
o   OK / OK to run

Comment: Hey no problemmo, it was an interesting expedition. Btw, I was just skimming over my post and realized I forgot two small bits in #4 and #5. The ODBCConnection is a child object of the WorkbookConnection object, like this: `WorkbookConnection` > `ODBCConnection`. Don't hesitate to hit me back if you have questions.

Comment: spinjector - Thanks for the follow-up and correction. Also, thank you for you GREATLY for your offer for further help. I'm in meeting all week and tied up with z/OS work most of next... will get back to this as soon as I am able and will keep you posted.